# Creating a 'for' loop in R

Tags: r

I'm having a little R situation that I can't get my head around.

Supposedly the code for this should only take two or 3 lines

What I have to do is figure out how many samples of 10 variables I have to take before I have seen every number once.

In other words, how many rolls of a dice (in this case with 10 sides) it takes before I have seen every side

so far I have something along these lines

```
    param<-1:10
    count<-0
    seen<-0
    for (i in 1:10) {
      if (sample(param, size=1)==i);
        if i in seen;
          count+=1
          seen+=1
        elif count+=1
    when seen==10 return(count) 
    }
```

but this is waaay too long, also I know the formatting of it isn't right (pretty sure I'm trying to use python code at some points) but this is the first time I have done a loop in R.

Any help would be much appreciated!

yes, this is for a project but I can't think of anything else.
yes, i have tried looking at other questions/answers for help but my brain is just in a muddle now

Comment: Your current code only rolls the dice 10 times, and checks for a different number each time (if it's currently the 5th roll, it will only check for a 5). If you're familiar with python, maybe try writing it out in that first so you're sure you have the logic right.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die

Comment: how do I make it so that there isnt a specific amount of times to roll the dice? like the whole point of what my code is trying to do is figure out how many rolls it takes. so i want it to stop once Ive seen all the values from one to ten

Comment: If you want something to repeat until a condition is met, you can use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for shorter code:

```
set.seed(1984)

n = 10
param = 1:n
count = 0

while(length(param) != 0){             ## stop when all numbers are seen
 param = setdiff(param, sample(1:n,1)) ## remove the element
 count = count + 1
}

count

## 28
```

***Edit (slightly vectorized approach)***

```
set.seed(1984)

n = 10
param = 1:n
count = 0

while(length(param) != 0){
  count = count + length(param)
  param = setdiff(param, sample(1:n,length(param),replace=T))
}

count

## 28
```

***Edit 2 (multiple runs)***

```
set.seed(1984)

n = 10
num.runs = 5
count = rep(0,5)

for(i in 1:num.runs)
{
  param = 1:n
  while(length(param) != 0){
    count[i] = count[i] + length(param)
    param = setdiff(param, sample(1:n,length(param),replace=T))
  }
}

count

## 28 24 23 30 23
```

Comment: thanks @PaulHiemstra. I was thinking if its possible to vectorize a loop that runs variable number of times (depending on the seed)?

Comment: edited: basically if I am yet to see `3` numbers, then I sample `3` at a time. So in the beginning `sample size = 10`.

Comment: is there a way to do it such that it repeats the entire code n times? as in, when I take out set.seed I get a bunch of different numbers for count so I want to be able to analyse the mean, sd etc of multiple counts

Comment: Sure, an outer `for` loop running `m` times to create a list of `count`

Comment: A more R-like solution would be to wrap the code in a function and use `replicate`. I edited an example into the answer of @Andrie.

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorise this problem by deliberately oversampling. In this example, I create a sampling vector of length 1000, then use `sapply` to find the solution:

**Edited**, to use `match` rather than `sapply`, as suggested by @MadScone

```
set.seed(1984)
n <- 10

x <- sample(n, 1e3, replace=TRUE)
max(match(1:n, x))
[1] 28
```

And if you want to repeat the experiement, you can use `replicate`:

```
do_experiment = function() {
    n <- 10
    x <- sample(n, 1e3, replace=TRUE)
    return(max(match(1:n, x)))
}
replicate(100, do_experiment())
 [1] 28 26 26 15 30 14 29 18 35 24 24 35 42 20 29 18 18 38 14 22 26 26 22 29 31
 [26] 51 14 35 26 19 40 22 23 19 28 15 27 20 16 18 20 19 18 37 24 38 37 54 29 19
 [51] 22 22 14 17 33 22 35 15 32 23 35 27 22 18 30 31 38 36 26 31 43 27 23 21 40
 [76] 25 36 21 39 27 55 28 36 15 48 31 32 46 28 21 40 23 46 24 31 30 25 21 24 20
```

Comment: +1, although I would not say this solution is vectorized, using `sapply` is still a loop...

Comment: nice, but might fail for larger `n`. Or even `n=10` in rare case :)

Comment: @e4e5f4 Correct, you need to have a good guess of how much to oversample.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra could do `max(match(1:n, x))` instead of the `sapply` for more vectorisedness.

Comment: @Andrie edited in a method of running the analysis repeatedly.